# How can I fill in the data from another table based on a single attribute

Tags: mysql

I have two tables where once I delete the table based on a single attribute, it would log it in another table. For example if I delete the user based on the id, it would fill it in the log table that the "'user's first name and last name' was deleted from the table"

| userid | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |

my sql for the delete is

```
DELETE FROM cars WHERE userid=1;
```

But I need to input it in a table called logs

Comment: Use a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger.

Comment: What can I write so that it takes the first name and last name then Adds it to the logs table

Comment: I already told you: write a trigger. I'm not going to code it for you.

Comment: I mean is there an sql statement that I can do like where select first name from cars where user id =1, and then format it in a VAARCHAR? or is that not possible in mysql

Comment: `INSERT INTO log SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname, ' was deleted') FROM cars WHERE userid = 1`

Comment: Thank you I just didn't know about the CONCAT command. sorry for making it seem like I wanted you to do that code

Comment: Your question is very unclear about what your problem is. Nowhere did you ask how to concatenate strings in MySQL.